# Как правильно реализовать получение данных из чужой системы?

Tags: база-данных, архитектура

У нас с продактом в который раз уже возникает спор, что из чужой БД читать -- такая себе история.
Мои аргументы:

- могут схемы поменяться
- могут способы заполнения данных измениться

Давай лучше на асинхронных контрактах жить

Его аргументы:

- контракты тоже могут измениться и способ заполнения данных может поменяться.

Где и что я упускаю?

Comment: Я не уверен, что конкретно здесь имеется в виду под «асинхронными контрактами», но что-то мне подсказывает, что поддерживать их стабильными будет намного проще чем поддерживать стабильность схемы БД (или даже сам факт существования БД, ведь данные не только в БД могут быть)

Comment: Цивилизованный мир уже давно использует GraphQL

Comment: 1. Поясните, пожалуйста, что такое «асинхронные контракты»? Термин не гуглится.

Comment: 2. О каких объёмах данных речь, и каков интервал актуализации, то есть через какое время после появления данных в чужой системе они должны гарантированно появиться у вас?

Answer (score 4):

*Поменяться* может все что угодно, как любая схема, так и протокол, и права доступа и вообще *добро* на взаимодействие между системами.

Подобное решение лежит не в сфере области программирования, а в заключенном "контракте" между вами и "чужими". Такой контракт описывает некоторое API *(англ. Application Programming Interface — описание способов взаимодействия одной компьютерной программы с другими)*, способ реализации которого, обычно разделяемый на сам формат и на его транспорт - уже детали. Будут это фиксированные таблицы БД, хранимки, или REST + xml/json в каком-либо формате, ftp+csv, или ещё что-угодно - обговаривается с "чужими".

Если "чужие" имеют некоторый жизненный опыт, то их API будет отделен (decoupled) от их основной системы (можно рассматривать их систему как Model, а API - как View) и либо максимально лаконичен (KISS and DRY), либо реализован по какому-либо общепринятому стандарту вашей предметной области (например Dicom).

Answer (score 0):

1. Читать из чужой БД - на мой взгляд хуже, потому что вы должны чётко разбираться в чужой базе. А там реально может поменяться всё, что угодно, данные могут вообще в другие таблицы переехать, например.
2. Некий контракт в виде `API`, некой витрины/вьюхи/процедуры в базе и т.п. - лучше, потому что вам не нужно знать их базу досконально, достаточно знать, как обратиться к предоставляемому вам заранее описанному интерфейсу. А те, кто ведут эту базу, лучше знают, как из их базы предоставить нужные данные в заранее обговоренном формате.

Да, в обоих вариантах будут сложности при каких-то изменениях в БД-источнике, но теоретически они должны лучше перевариваться во втором варианте. Хотя, конечно, универсальных решений нет - например, БД может вести один человек, который весь в задачах и ему некогда заниматься ещё и этим `API`, оно у него по остаточному принципу, ему главное, чтобы база работала 24/7. А у вас при этом полно времени и компетенций, чтобы самим разбираться с изменениями в БД. В этом случае первый вариант будет удобнее, чем ждать, пока у этого админа появится время и желание исправлять `API`.

Comment: API это договоренность, не ограничивающаяся бинарными пакетами. В том числе может быть и в виде "вот в эти "публичные" таблички мы будем складывать то что вам надо, в таком-то виде, права на чтение будут у вашего user_guest", и даже "каждую пятницу в дупле у опушки будет флэшка с паролем *qwerty* с Excel файлом".

Comment: @Kromster, "если к 18:00 флешки нет, то явка провалена, подчищайте хвосты и покидайте страну" ))